# postgresql dynamically name columns in case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, transpose

I'm looking for a way to dynamically or automatically name the columns in my case statement below.  Scenario - I'm trying to find out how many different companies of various industries are found in each country.  The countries are the rows while the categories are the columns.

I'm using postgressql so pivot won't work and I don't have a new enough version where I can use cross-tab

I want to be able to replicate this for much larger scenarios where I won't have to worry about 'hardcoding' the cat_nbr and column names like I do here.

```
SELECT country,
       count(CASE WHEN cat_nbr = 1 THEN company_code END) retail,
       count(CASE WHEN cat_nbr = 2 THEN company_code END) finance,
       count(CASE WHEN cat_nbr = 3 THEN company_code END) oil,
       count(CASE WHEN cat_nbr = 4 THEN company_code END) tech   
FROM global_companies  
GROUP BY country
```

the table structure format in case it isn't clear has these columns:

```
country - cat_nbr - company_code -  cat_desc.
```

`Cat_desc` is where I have hardcoded the words 'retail', 'finance', etc

Is there someway I can do this with less hardcoding in terms of what I refer to each cat_nbr/cat_desc?   There are lots and lots of cat_nbrs and cat_descs.

Comment: Postgresql version? You have a table cat_nbr?

Comment: You need to create a function and create a dinamic query similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965882/for-loop-with-dynamic-table-name-in-postgresql-9-1)  But instead you will LOOP between your category table.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza.   Cat_nbr and retail/finance go together.  E.g, category #1 = retail, #2=finance, etc.  Translates into words what is going on.     Version is something in the 7s, can't check exactly atm.

Comment: But you have those in a table or are constant somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You can not create a query with a dynamic row size. That's impossible, even with cross-tab.

You can however

1. create a query that returns a SQL statement which you can execute afterward, in the client.
2. create something like `\crosstabview` with the client.

You can read more information about this in my question, [*"How do I generate a pivoted CROSS JOIN where the resulting table definition is unknown?"*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/159280/2639).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding category names, you could hardcode country names for the columns and let the rows be dynamic as usual.

```
SELECT cat_nbr, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'US' THEN company_code END) AS NumUS,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'UK' THEN company_code END) AS NumUK,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'FR' THEN company_code END) AS NumFR,
       ...
FROM global_companies
GROUP BY cat_nbr;
```

Another alternative is you can aggregate the data into JSON or array structures.